# Selenium RC find element that have a specific string at the start of the class

Tags: c#, css, selenium

I have more Items that have the same string in the class name, lets say the string is "dummy", 
The problem is that I cannot do this with things like `tr[class^='dummy']` because this class is under different tags and the class attribute can contain more then one CSS class.

Is there a possibility to identify this elements without using switch to identify them ?

Comment: I think i found the solution after all with driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".dummy")) I seams to work.

Comment: If you are sure that it answers your question, you could add it as an answer. In this way others can use your solution, when they find themselves running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".dummy"))
```

With this the first element that have this class is returned.